# Avoid unused assets Angular

Tags: angular, webpack

From the documentation I can see that Angular copies the `assets/` dir as-is. So, I was wondering if there's a way to avoid that behaviour, and only copying the assets that are actually used somewhere in my application.

I've seen projects (webpack, though not Angular) that have the following config:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'html-loader',
      options: {
        minimize: true,
        attrs: ['img:src', 'video:poster', 'source:src']
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif|webm|mp4|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
        context: 'src'
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

This only copies the assets that are present in an HTML file.

Can this be achieved in an Angular project?

Comment: I wish some one would answer this.

Comment: Why bother? The assets are not part of the bundle, they are just copied to the output folder to be served by whatever static content delivery you use. The browser never sees or downloads them if the aren't referenced in src. Another use case for assets would be to AJAX them (HttpClient), e.g. for lazy-loading data. This would not be detected and you'd run into problems that are hard to debug (only appear in prod).

Comment: You can store your assets elsewhere and use relative paths when using them. This way webpack will include only those assets and also add a hash to them

Comment: I think the better question is: why are you adding files to your assets folder that are not being used? Considering angular can access these files using dynamically, even user created names, it would be impossible for angular to know if a file may or may not be used.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way of doing this with Angular 13 out of the box.

However, you could write an angular builder or add a postbuild script to your package.json

Assuming you're adding a postbuild script:

Read the relevant files in your project and write a function to search for the asset paths:

```
fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, filenames) {
   filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
     fs.readFile(dirname + filename, 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
       const inUse = searchForAssetUse(filename, content);
       if(!inUse) fs.unlinkSync(dirname + filename) //remove the file if it's not in use
     });
   });
 });
```

That way you only bundle assets that are in use in your project. You can add the script to your package.json

Note the postbuild script will run after the build script automatically

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng run project:prerender",
    "postbuild": "node cleanAssets.js"
    ...
}
```

Comment: that's not an answer, it require a working example, please if you have anything that's not an answer write it as comment instead of answer